# How will this code will work on a big endian machine?

Tags: c, endianness

If I have the code:

```
uint64_t a = 0x1111222233334444;
uint32_t b = 0;
b = a;
printf("a is %llx ",a);
printf("b is %x ",b);
```

and the output is :

```
 a is 1111222233334444 b is 33334444
```

**Questions** :

1. Will the behavior be same on big-endian machine?
2. If I assign a's value in b or do a typecast will the result be same in big endian?

Comment: Note that you should print those values with `PRIx64` and `PRIx32`, respectively.

Comment: ya man..but indirectly both are same

Comment: Not on every machine. It's best to write code that won't break 10 years from now when they decide 128-bits isn't enough memory for personal computers, and suddenly `sizeof(long) == sizeof(int)` isn't true anymore.

Comment: @ Chris Lutz ya i got ur point now onwards i will keep this in ma mind..!! thnks bro..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code you have there will work the same way. This is because the behavior of downcasting is defined by the C standard.

However, if you did this:

```
uint64_t a = 0x0123456789abcdefull;
uint32_t b = *(uint32_t*)&a;
printf("b is %x",b)
```

Then it will be endian-dependent.

EDIT:

Little Endian: b is 89abcdef

Big Endian   : b is 01234567

Comment: so you mean this will give different result in both way..??

Comment: +1 Note that only unsigned downcast is defined in the standard. Signed downcast is "implementation-defined", meaning that the compiler noly needs to do something consistent and document it.

Comment: For this example that I gave: On little-endian, the result is 89abcdef. On big-endian, the result will probably be 01234567.

Comment: Or simply try `printf("a is %X", a);`.

Answer (score 1):

When assigning variables, compiler handles things for you, so result will be the same on big-endian.

When typecasting pointers to memory, result will NOT be the same on big-endian.

Answer (score 0):

direct assignment will yield the same result on both little endian and big endian.

memory typecast on big endian machine will output

a is 1111222233334444 b is 11112222