# printf not printing the correct values

Tags: c++, c, printf

I wrote a small code of C.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a  = 0;
    printf("Hello  World %llu is here %d\n",a, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

It is printing the following ouput

> Hello  World 4294967296 is here -1216225312

With the following warning on compilation

> prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
>
> prog.cpp:5: warning: format ‘%llu’ expects type ‘long long unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’

I know i need to cast the int to long long unsigned int, but i could not understand the fact that why the later values got corrupted.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Very similar to the recent http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295066/using-printf-to-print-out-floating-values

Answer (score 7, accepted):

%llu expects a 64-bit integer. But you only gave it a 32-bit integer.

The effect is that what printf is reading is "shifted" over by 32-bits with respect to what you've passed. Hence your "1" is not being read in the right location.

EDIT:

Now to explain the output:

`a` and `1` are being stored 32-bits apart because they are both 32-bit integers.
However, printf expects the first argument to be a 64-bit integer. Hence it reads it as `a + 2^32 * 1` which is `4294967296` in your case. The second value that is printed is undefined because it is past the `1`.

Comment: @Mystical Can you please explain how you got (a + 2^32 * 1) ? Thanks

Comment: This has to do with the memory layout of the system. A 32-bit integer is stored as 4 consecutive bytes. Similarly, a 64-bit integer is stored as 8 consecutive bytes. 'A' and '1' are both 32-bit integers stored consecutively in memory upon calling 'printf()', but 'printf()' will read it as a 64-bit integer. So it will read both of them together as 8 bytes holding a 64-bit integer, where 'a' is holding the lower 32-bits and '1' is the high 32-bits. Hence a + 2^32 * 1. This probably sounds really confusing - maybe someone can explain better.

Comment: @Mystical: I find the explanation fine, I would note that this depends greatly on the endianness of the system (the same memory would be processed as `2^32+a` if endianness was shifted) and in the way that the compiler decided to layout the local variables in `main` which is not mandated by the standard (it could have decided to store them in the opposite order). So while the explanation is fine to understand the behavior, it cannot be safely used to predict the behavior on any platform or with any other compiler or compiler flags.

Comment: @David: Yes, I'm well aware of the endian dependency, but I'm trying not to make it any more confusing than it already is. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266332/how-will-this-code-will-work-on-a-big-endian-machine/7266349) On big-endian it would probably be 1 + 2^32 * a.

Comment: @Mystical Thanks for your explanation. Is it always a & 1 are stored in consecutive bytes?. What will happen, if I have another variable say b instead of 1.

Comment: It's not defined, so anything is "allowed" to happen. I'm actually not sure if the parameters are always stored consecutively. In this case, they are the same size, so they probably will. However, if they aren't the same size, there may be alignment padding. I don't know the answer to this though.

Answer (score 4):

Because the code causes an **Undefined Behavior**.
An Undefined Behavior inherently means tha all bets are off.

`printf` is not type safe. You have to be careful in telling `printf` the proper format desrciptor while printing out types.

Comment: As a further comment, this applies to all "variable argument" functions. They cannot tell what types are passed in unless explicitly told, such as the format string in `printf`

Comment: +1. This is correct answer, as the behavior of the program is undefined.

Answer (score 3):

The format you passed to `printf()` leads it to expect 12 bytes on the stack, but you only push 8 bytes.  So, it reads 4 bytes you didn't push, and gives you unexpected output.

Make sure you pass what `printf()` expects, and heed your compiler's warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Long long is 64 bits long, therefore what happens is this :
1. printf grabs 64-bits and print it as the 1st argument
2. then it grabs 32 bit at the offset of 64 bits, and print it

Since you are passing 32 bits value to the 1st argument, both values are garbage

Answer (score 0):

According to given format, printf reads memory region 64 bit length, which contains a and 1 together, an prints 4294967296. Then it reads some junk from the next 32 bits and prints -1216225312.